# how to position an item to match sceptic item in column

Tags: flutter, dart

i have the following code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      Stack(
        children: [
          Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            body: ListView.builder(
              itemCount:  1,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 300),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: const [
                          Icon(Icons.circle, color: Colors.yellowAccent),
                          Spacer(),
                          Icon(Icons.circle, color: Colors.red),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        child: const Text('hello world Hello dart'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                );
              },
            ),
          ),

        ],
      );
  }
```

output

[image]

but i am trying to make the output like following

[image]

Note: the text is not fixed in size , and i am trying to position the red circle always to match the max available text width

How to handle it in best way

Answer (score 0):

### #Update

### lats tested on `dart 3.1.0` and `flutter 3.12.0`

since in the comment said that the image and code doesnt macth. I'll put demo link below

## https://dartpad.dev/?id=bacda3921056a0c74ff64216a06a03f7

---

### *initial answer

You can use `Stack` widget and `Positioned` widget. Something like `position:absolute` in css

[image]

```
body: Center(
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Container(
        child: Stack(children: [
          /// example 1
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 24),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: const Text('hello world Hello dart'),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            child: Icon(Icons.circle, color: Colors.yellowAccent),
          ),
          Positioned(
            right: 0,
            top: 0,
            child: Icon(Icons.circle, color: Colors.red),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
      Divider(),

      /// example 2
      Container(
        child: Stack(children: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 24),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: const Text(
                'hello world asdajsflshaflhdslfdhdlfhdslhg sdjfsdjfsdlfksdf Hello dart'),
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            child: Icon(Icons.circle, color: Colors.yellowAccent),
          ),
          Positioned(
            right: 0,
            top: 0,
            child: Icon(Icons.circle, color: Colors.red),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

and also, you need to remove unecessary widget

```
 // Stack( << remove this
 // children: [  << remove this
    Scaffold(
       backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      // use ListView.builder only for very long list data
      // body: ListView.builder(  << remove this
      // itemCount:  1,  << remove this
      // itemBuilder: << remove this

     // use ListView instead,
     body: Listview(
       children:[ 
  .... rest of code
```

Comment: thanks for answering my question , since i include ListView.builder so it clear that my list is long , i have large items on it and i want the expected desired in Column not Stack , you gave instead way but not solving the issue in my question it's self

Comment: also the output in you image does not match the code you written . it seem to be the items in stack will never go out the blue container its self

Comment: no, what i mean for long list are, the  `itemCount`  property in you widget. VERY CLEAR that item count in you listview  = `1` . the defenition long list are more than thousand. HOPE YOU UNDERSTAND

Comment: everyone are very welcome into community,  special for you, let me intoduce playground name DARTPAD.  
here the demo for my code https://dartpad.dev/?id=bacda3921056a0c74ff64216a06a03f7

Comment: @MohammedHamdan happy learning.

Comment: now i am using SuperColumn plugin and it done my need , and ues i tested your code .. it does not match the output on that image

Comment: Glad you chose third party plugin, its good solution for you to.

Comment: but I've provided the link to dartpad, and you keep saying the image doesn't match the code?  maybe it was attached by magic.          

Comment: not magic , if you have the latest release of flutter you will understand why your code does not meet the image provided

Comment: then... did you know that `dartpad` uses the latest  version of `dart` and `flutter`?
I'm sure you don't know. because you're just in denial about it. instead of trying it.

Comment: good luck on you journey in flutter and dart. Happy coding,

Comment: then why you wrapping unnecessary containers ? , i did not say dartpad not meet your image , but trust me when i copy you code into my IDE the circles always not go out the range as provided in your image

Comment:   . Ok now i get it. The mistake is in your code but blame my answer doesn't work in latest version of flutter. I'm have no problem this solution not fit to your code, because `this is just an minimal reproduce example`

Comment: i copied it as it not from my side